# How to access elements of a vector in a Rcpp::List

Tags: r, rcpp

I am puzzled.

The following compile and work fine:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test(){
    List l;
    IntegerVector v(5, NA_INTEGER);
    l.push_back(v);
    return l;
}
```

In R:

```
R) test()
[[1]]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

But when I try to set the `IntegerVector` in the list:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test(){
    List l;
    IntegerVector v(5, NA_INTEGER);
    l.push_back(v);
    l[0][1] = 1;
    return l;
}
```

It does not compile:

```
test.cpp:121:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct SEXPREC'
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.0/include/Rinternals.h:393:16: error: forward declaration of 'struct SEXPREC'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
l[0][1] = 1;
```

The compiler has no idea that `l` is a list of integer vectors. In essence `l[0]` gives you a `SEXP` (the generic type for all R objects), and `SEXP` is an opaque pointer to `SEXPREC` of which we don't have access to te definition (hence opaque). So when you do the `[1]`, you attempt to get the second `SEXPREC` and so the opacity makes it impossible, and it is not what you wanted anyway.

You have to be specific that you are extracting an `IntegerVector`, so you can do something like this:

```
as<IntegerVector>(l[0])[1] = 1;
```

or

```
v[1] = 1 ;
```

or

```
IntegerVector x = l[0] ; x[1] = 1 ;
```

All of these options work on the same underlying data structure.

Alternatively, if you really wanted the syntax `l[0][1]` you could define your own data structure expressing "list of integer vectors". Here is a sketch:

```
template <class T>
class ListOf {
public:

    ListOf( List data_) : data(data_){}

    T operator[](int i){
        return as<T>( data[i] ) ;
    }
    operator List(){ return data ; }

private:
    List data ;
} ;
```

Which you can use, e.g. like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test2(){
    ListOf<IntegerVector> l = List::create( IntegerVector(5, NA_INTEGER) ) ; 
    l[0][1] = 1 ;
    return l;
}
```

Also note that using `.push_back` on `Rcpp` vectors (including lists) requires a complete copy of the list data, which can cause slow you down. Only use resizing functions when you don't have a choice.

Comment: One more question Romain, can I create a `Rcpp::List` containing `n` (say 3) `std::vector<int>` or `Rcpp::IntegerVector` with a one-liner (may be a `ctor`), like `IntegerVector v(3,NA_INTEGER); Rcpp::List test(3,v)`

Comment: This is intended to work: `List l( 3, IntegerVector(3,NA_INTEGER) )`, but there is a typo in one of our file (`fill__dispatch` is spelled as `fill_dispatch` (one underscore) ), so it fails. I fixed it locally and will commit the fix soon enough.