# Rcpp: Dealing with Lists that include Lists

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

Let's first generate some lists with lists inside:

```
lappend <- function(lst, ...){
  lst <- c(lst, list(...))
  return(lst)
}

scalarList <- list()
vectorList <- list()
MatrixList <- list()

for (i in 1:3){
  scalarList <- lappend(scalarList,i)
  vectorList <- lappend(vectorList,0:i)
  MatrixList <- lappend(MatrixList, diag(i + 1))
}

myRList <- list(scalarList = scalarList, vectorList = vectorList, 
  MatrixList = MatrixList)
```

Now that our myRList is ready, I'd like to write a function in C++ as follows:

1) inputs: 1) myRList, 2) an id from 1 to 3

2) output: the function should separately print scalar, vector, and matrix corresponding to the input id.

3) There might be many ways to write this function. I specifically want to read-in the list an assign it to a corresponding arma object and then print it. The reason is I wrote this simplified example to learn from you guys on how to extract elements of a list within another list in Rcpp and assign it to an arma object.

Here is my C++ code:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double myListExtractor( Rcpp::List aList_In_R, int id){
int myScalar = Rcpp::as<double>(aList_In_R["scalarList"][id]); //? what to do ?
arma::vec myVector = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(aList_In_R["vectorList"[id]]); //???
arma::mat myMatrix = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(aList_In_R["MatrixList"[id]]); //???

// If I manage to do the three assignments above, then printing is easy:

Rcpp::Rcout << "myScalar = " << myScalar << std::endl;
Rcpp::Rcout << "myVector = " << myVector << std::endl; 
Rcpp::Rcout << "myMatrix = " << myMatrix << std::endl;

return 1; // we don't care about the return for now
}
```

Again, I 100% agree that there is no need to assign them to arma objects and then print. In my own code I do lots of algebra with the arma objects and that's the reason I'm emphasizing on this assignment to learn how to fix my code/

Thank you very much in advance for your help. Also, I spent 3 hours browsing the Net and I didn't find any answer.

Comment: One solution is to call the function on each of the sublists, or intead of calling the function on myRList, we can supply the function with three arguments of myRList$scalarList, myRList$vectorList, and myRList$MatrixList and work with each separately

Comment: A search for `[rcpp] List` has 183 results.  Did you search first?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, good morning. Yes, I did. There are a lot of useful answers on retrieving an element from a List as you also explained in your book. I didn't find any question/answer on dealing with a list that includes subLists.

Comment: I am pretty sure we answered that somewhere too.  And _conceptually_ it really is the same: you fetch a `SEXP` from a List. Which happens to be a List from which you fetch a `SEXP` which ...

Comment: You're right -- this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407762/how-to-access-elements-of-a-vector-in-a-rcpplist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `List` objects don't know anything about the type of objects they contain, you must `as` at each level of subsetting. Eg:

```
int myScalar = Rcpp::as<double>( Rcpp::as<Rcpp::List>(aList_In_R["scalarList"])[id] );
```

This way, we can signal to the compiler that the slot we're extracting from `aList_In_R` is a `List`, and all the methods we have for `List`s should apply here. It's ugly, but it's an unfortunate consequence on using a statically typed language to operate on objects used in a dynamically typed language.

There is some work on getting templated list containers into `Rcpp` that might help with this situation; e.g. instead of having a `List` you might have a `ListOf< List >` whereby the subset operator would 'know' that it should return `List` after subsetting, which could be a bit nicer. Perhaps it could go as deep as `ListOf< ListOf< double > >`, etc...

Comment: Hi @KevinUshey, perfect answer. My issue is now completely solved. Thanks very much.